# Update data to array column Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I wouldike to send some data to my column (type array)
But the syntax doesn't work...

```
UPDATE car
    SET ctn_color = array_cat(ctn_color, '{red,blue}');
    WHERE ctn_identifiant_car='CONT_ABC';
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: The syntax looks OK. What problem hare you having with it?

Comment: redundant semicolon after '{red,blue}') ?